# how to type hint collections.OrderedDict via python 3.5 typing module

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

I want to use an OrderedDict where the key is a Enum and where the item is a certain class.

How do I use the typing module to hint this?
What is the analog to this hinted namedtuple::

```
Move = typing.NamedTuple('Move', [('actor', Actor), ('location', Location)])
```

Comment: But if I do that, how is YourDict an OrderedDict?

Comment: You could use `typing.MutableMapping`, if you need a specific type for OrderedDict you would have to create it `class OrderedDictType(OrderedDict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in a comment by AChampion, you can use `MutableMapping`:

```
class Actor(Enum):
    # ...Actor enum menbers...

class Location:
    # ...Location class body...

class MapActor2Location(OrderedDict, MutableMapping[Actor, Location]):
    pass
```

---

Addendum for people like me who haven't used the `typing` module before: note that the type definitions use indexing syntax (`[T]`) **without** parentheses. I initially tried something like this:

```
class MyMap(OrderedDict, MutableMapping([KT, VT])): pass
```

(Note the extraneous parentheses around `[KT, VT]`!)

This gives what I consider a rather confusing error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MutableMapping with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, __setitem__
```

Comment: For the addendum, I realize that there's no good reason why parentheses would make any sense where I put them, but the fact remains that that's what my fingers produced without me really even noticing, and the error message wasn't *quite* as helpful as I'd have liked. I went down the rabbit hole of `abc`'s "virtual subclasses" before figuring out I'd made a basic syntax mistake.

Comment: Inheriting from `MutableSequence` makes no sense, as this type is not a sequence, and the mapping and sequence APIs are incompatible.

Comment: @user2357112 The *entire point* of an `OrderedDictionary` is to be a sequentially iterable type with guaranteed iteration order (unlike a normal `dict`). This is how a sequence [is defined by `abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). And, again, note that this is confirmed by the error that occurs when you *don't* inherit from `MutableSequence`.

Comment: @user2357112 I've edited the answer to explain why `MutableSequence` is necessary.

Comment: A sequence is accessed through sequential *integer indices*. Guaranteed iteration order is only part of the sequence API.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct! I think I may have accidentally typed something like `Foo[Actor.fred]` instead of `x[Actor.fred]`. Thank you for providing a working example. I have removed all mentions of `MutableSequence` from my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The question is about 3.5, but `typing.OrderedDict` was [introduced in the python 3.7.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.OrderedDict). So you can write:

```py
from typing import OrderedDict
Movie = OrderedDict[Actor, Location]
```

or with backward compatibility workaround suggested by AChampion

```py
try:
    from typing import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    from typing import MutableMapping
    OrderedDict = MutableMapping
Movie = OrderedDict[Actor, Location]
```

Comment: How about `except ImportError: from typing import MutableMapping as OrderedDict`?

Comment: @connectyourcharger `MutableMapping` have been introduced in 3.6.0, if you change `MutableMapping` to `Any` you can reach backward compatibility back to 3.5, having proper types checking in 3.7.2 and "working code" in 3.5+