# How do I specify OrderedDict K,V types for Mypy type annotation?

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting, mypy

I am using Python 3.5 together with Mypy to have some basic static checking for my script. Recently I refactored some methods to return OrderedDict, but ran into "'type' object is not subscriptable" error, when I tried to use return annotation with Key and Value types specified.

Reduced example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

from collections import OrderedDict

# this works
def foo() -> OrderedDict:
    result = OrderedDict() # type: OrderedDict[str, int]
    result['foo'] = 123
    return result

# this doesn't
def foo2() -> OrderedDict[str, int]:
    result = OrderedDict() # type: OrderedDict[str, int]
    result['foo'] = 123
    return result

print(foo())
```

And this is python output when it is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 12, in <module>
    def foo2() -> OrderedDict[str, int]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Mypy however has no problem with the type annotation in comment and will in fact warn if I try to do `result[123] = 123`.

What is causing this?

Comment: It works now (mypy version 0.501).

Comment: Just depositing a link to the fix: https://bugs.python.org/issue35341

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no problem in mypy (at least, not in 0.501).
But there *is* a problem with Python 3.6.0.
Consider the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from typing import Dict

def foo() -> Dict[str, int]:
    result: OrderedDict[str, int] = OrderedDict()
    result['two'] = 2
    return result
```

This code will both satisfy mypy (0.501) and Python (3.6.0).
However, if you replace `Dict` with `OrderedDict`, then mypy will still be happy, but executing it will die with `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

It is interesting that the Python interpreter dies on seeing a subscripted `OrderedDict` in the function signature, but is happy to accept it in a variable type annotation.

At any rate, my workaround for this is to use `Dict` instead of `OrderedDict` in the function signature (and add a comment that this should be fixed if/when the Python interpreter will learn to accept the correct signature).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the same workaround in my own code.

Comment: This is causing an error in mypy 0.063 but the answer suggesting changing the function signature into a string works.

Comment: Python [3.7.2 introduces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.OrderedDict) `typing.OrderedDict`

Comment: The `typing.OrderedDict` introduced in 3.7.2 is again deprecated in 3.9, which adds support for `collections.OrderedDict[K, V]`.

Comment: Another workaround is to quote the type in function signature, e.g. `'OrderedDict[...]'`

Comment: Using these comments to voice my complaint that I can't import both `collections.OrderedDict` and `typing.OrderedDict` into the same namespace like `from typing import OrderedDict; from collections import OrderedDict`

Answer (score 17):

As a workaround, you can also put the return type into a string to satisfy both Mypy and Python 3.6:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def foo() -> 'OrderedDict[str, int]':
    result = OrderedDict()
    result['foo'] = 123
    return result
```

Answer (score 6):

collections.OrderedDict is not the same that typing.OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict as collections_OrderedDict
from typing import OrderedDict

# this works
def foo() -> OrderedDict[str, int]:
    result = collections_OrderedDict()
    result['foo'] = 123
    return result

print(foo())
```

Comment: Point taken, but why not just `import collections; result=collections.OrderedDict()`

Answer (score 2):

What you can also try is using `MutableMapping` (like in this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167921/1386610)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from typing import Dict

def foo() -> MutableMapping[str, int]:
    result = OrderedDict() # type: MutableMapping[str, int]
    result['foo'] = 123
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version allowed this, but a better solution  as for March/24/2021, tested for Python 3.7.5:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import typing

def foo() -> typing.OrderedDict[str, int]:
    result: typing.OrderedDict[str, int] = OrderedDict()
    result['two'] = 2
    return result
```

Enjoy all worlds!

Comment: For 3.7, I tried `suggestions: OrderedDict[str, Any] = OrderedDict()` but there is a red squiggly under `OrderedDict()` saying `Generics should be specified through square brackets`. But simply replacing () with [] doesn't fix it too because now it expects an expression within [].

Not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: @perennial_noob Please write exactly the code that gives you the error. Also, are you using 3.7.5+?

Comment: I am actually using 3.8.7. Yeah so I am using Pycharm and it suggests the `[]` fix. I clicked on it to let it fix it but now it wants an expression. Not sure if I am supposed to init a value with None like `suggestions: OrderedDict[str, Any] = OrderedDict[dummykey]`

I even tried `suggestions: OrderedDict[str, Any] = {}` but then the linter warns that it is expecting OrderedDict but got a Dict instead.

Comment: Try `suggestions: OrderedDict[str, Any] = OrderedDict()` and `suggestions[dummykey] = 1`