# How to subclass a dictionary so it supports generic type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, type-hinting, mypy

How can a dictionary be subclassed such that the subclass supports generic type hinting? It needs to behave like a dictionary in every way and support type hints of the keys and values.  The subclass will add functions that access and manipulate the dictionary data. For example, it will have a `valueat(self, idx:int)` function that returns the dictionary value at a given index.

It doesn't require `OrderedDict` as its base class, but the dictionary does need to have a predictable order. Since `OrderedDict` maintains insertion order and supports type hints, it seems like a reasonable place to start.
Here's what I tried:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class ApplicationSpecificDict(OrderedDict[str, int]):
    ...
```

However, it fails with the error:
`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Is this not supported in Python 3.7+, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can already type hint a regular dict with `typing.Dict[str, int]`. Were you looking for something else?

Comment: Not sure about the specifics of what you are trying to do, but based on what you are asking, dataclasses may be a more elegant solution to accomplish your goals.  They handle the typing, default values, and have a replace() method for updating.  They interoperate with dictionaries quite well too, including initializing with **dict_val and converting instance vars to a dict using its asdict() method if you really need pure dict functionality.

Comment: @JohnS
Thanks. I'm using `dataclass` in several modules. What is lacking in `dataclass` is the behavior of a `dict` (obviously; however one could add that by implementing `dict` methods as I've done in `TypedDict`) and also lacking support for type hinting. How would a user specify the key/value data types of the dataclass's `dict` data member?

Comment: The point of a dataclass is to not have any field but some well defined ones only.

Comment: @user2357112 The goal is to have class that acts like a dictionary class, but with additional methods to access and manipulate the dictionary entries consistent with the type hints of the keys and values.

Comment: It looks like this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736275/how-to-type-hint-collections-ordereddict-via-python-3-5-typing-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to type hint collections.OrderedDict via python 3.5 typing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736275/how-to-type-hint-collections-ordereddict-via-python-3-5-typing-module)

Comment: I also vote for dataclasses (python 3.7+). https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add type annotations to custom dict subclass in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427687/how-to-add-type-annotations-to-custom-dict-subclass-in-python)

Answer (score 14):

The [**typing**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) package provides generic classes that correspond to the non-generic classes in [**collections.abc**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) and [**collections**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections). These generic classes may be used as base classes to create user-defined generic classes, such as a custom generic dictionary.

#### Examples of generic classes corresponding to types in `collections.abc`:

- `typing.AbstractSet(Sized, Collection[T_co])`
- `typing.Container(Generic[T_co])`
- `typing.Mapping(Sized, Collection[KT], Generic[VT_co])`
- `typing.MutableMapping(Mapping[KT, VT])`
- `typing.MutableSequence(Sequence[T])`
- `typing.MutableSet(AbstractSet[T])`
- `typing.Sequence(Reversible[T_co], Collection[T_co])`

#### Examples of generic classes corresponding to types in `collections`:

- `typing.DefaultDict(collections.defaultdict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`
- `typing.OrderedDict(collections.OrderedDict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`
- `typing.ChainMap(collections.ChainMap, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`
- `typing.Counter(collections.Counter, Dict[T, int])`
- `typing.Deque(deque, MutableSequence[T])`

## Implementing a custom generic dictionary

There are many options for implementing a custom generic dictionary. However, it is important to note that unless the user-defined class explicitly inherits from `Mapping` or `MutableMapping`, static type checkers like [**mypy**](http://mypy-lang.org/) will not consider the class as a mapping.

#### Example user-defined generic dictionary

```
from collections import abc  # Used for isinstance check in `update()`.
from typing import Dict, Iterator, MutableMapping, TypeVar

KT = TypeVar('KT')
VT = TypeVar('VT')


class MyDict(MutableMapping[KT, VT]):

    def __init__(self, dictionary=None, /, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.data: Dict[KT, VT] = {}
        if dictionary is not None:
            self.update(dictionary)
        if kwargs:
            self.update(kwargs)
    
    def __contains__(self, key: KT) -> bool:
        return key in self.data

    def __delitem__(self, key: KT) -> None:
        del self.data[key]

    def __getitem__(self, key: KT) -> VT:
        if key in self.data:
            return self.data[key]
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[KT]:
        return iter(self.data)

    def __setitem__(self, key: KT, value: VT) -> None:
        self.data[key] = value
    
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, iterable: Iterable[KT], value: VT) -> "MyDict":
        """Create a new dictionary with keys from `iterable` and values set 
        to `value`.

        Args:
            iterable: A collection of keys.
            value: The default value. All of the values refer to just a single 
                instance, so it generally does not make sense for `value` to be a 
                mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use 
                a dict comprehension instead.

        Returns:
            A new instance of MyDict.
        """
        d = cls()
        for key in iterable:
            d[key] = value
        return d

    def update(self, other=(), /, **kwds) -> None:
        """Updates the dictionary from an iterable or mapping object."""
        if isinstance(other, abc.Mapping):
            for key in other:
                self.data[key] = other[key]
        elif hasattr(other, "keys"):
            for key in other.keys():
                self.data[key] = other[key]
        else:
            for key, value in other:
                self.data[key] = value
        for key, value in kwds.items():
            self.data[key] = value
```

Comment: Wow, what a nice template!!! Question: in `__getitem__()`, why the `key in self.data` test? Couldn't  it simply `return self.data[key]` directly, as it is expected of `data`'s `__getitem__` to raise `KeyError` itself?

Comment: @MestreLion The `__getitem__()` key check is so that in the event of a `KeyError`, the error originates from `MyDict` instead of the nested `MyDict.data` (which would needlessly expose an implementation detail).

Answer (score 8):

I posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427687/how-to-add-type-annotations-to-custom-dict-subclass-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) question which yours may be a dupe of, but I will include it here as well because I found both of these questions when I was googling how to do this.

Basically, you need to use the typing [Mapping generic](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-sub-classes-of-generic-classes)
This is the generic annotation that dict uses so you can define other types like `MyDict[str, int]`.

How to:

```
import typing
from collections import OrderedDict

# these are generic type vars to tell mutable-mapping 
# to accept any type vars when creating a sub-type of your generic dict
_KT = typing.TypeVar("_KT") #  key type
_VT = typing.TypeVar("_VT") #  value type


# `typing.MutableMapping` requires you to implement certain functions like __getitem__
# You can get around this by just subclassing OrderedDict first.
# Note: The generic you're subclassing needs to come BEFORE
# the `typing.MutableMapping` subclass or accessing indices won't work.

class ApplicationSpecificDict(
        OrderedDict, 
        typing.MutableMapping[_KT, _VT]
):
    """Your special dict"""
    ...

# Now define the key, value types for sub-types of your dict
RequestDict = ApplicationSpecificDict[str, typing.Tuple[str, str]]
ModelDict = ApplicationSpecificDict[str, typing.Any]
```

Now use you custom types of your sub-typed dict:

```
from my_project.custom_typing import ApplicationSpecificDict #  Import your custom type

def make_request() -> ApplicationSpecificDict:
    request = ApplicationSpecificDict()
    request["test"] = ("sierra", "117")
    return request

print(make_request())
```

Will output as `{ "test": ("sierra", "117") }`